# Parallel computing in Spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am not able to get my code to run when using n_jobs = -1(on the last line). 

I get the same message : 

"BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable."
The code works with n_jobs = 1, but I need all processors as the code will take very long to execute.
I have tried using `if __name__ == '__main__':` , but I am not sure how to use it and cannot get the code to run.
I have tried for ages but to no avail. Any help is highly appreciated. Here is the relevant code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_classifier():
   classifier = Sequential()
   classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
   classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
   classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
   classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
   return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier,batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```